# Chrome extension API and idle

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Sorry for cumbersome title, couldn't come up with more descriptive one.
The problem is when opened tab is left without user activity, for example user switched to another screen, Chrome stops rendering changes on that tab. Looks like any background activity is put on hold which is great from perspective of saving power and resources. But if user still needs to see all live updates what is the way to prevent tab to go to 'idle' state despite of having no user activity?
I was looking into `chrome.idle` API but it doesn't say how to prevent, only how to check.

Comment: Chrome allocates time budget to background tabs. The more CPU is consumed by a backgrounded tab, the more it is throttled.

Comment: @wOxxOm if I use 'chrome.idle' API to check status and set background tab active would that work? Just thinking if tab is background content script will stop working for the same reason. What about background script?

Comment: 1) AFAIK there's no way to affect it, 2) extension background/event page is not affected.